# Overriding CSS for list elements

Tags: 2010, css

I am having trouble finding a way to override CSS for RTF unordered and ordered lists on wiki pages and web content pages, without affecting other web parts in the master page, such as the quick launch text.

I have a custom master page that references my CSS file, mostly containing header, paragraph and table formatting tweaks. It seems that the answer lies in specifying the li/ul/ol settings for either the .ms-WPBody content area or manipulating the page layout, but I can't get this to work as expected.

When I override the general unordered list in my CSS, I can control all master page elements...

```
ul {
    color:blue;
    font-size: 15px;
    }
```

But how do I limit this to just the page content area that users will edit?

Comment: http://www.webteacher.ws/2011/12/07/css-selectors-101/

Answer (score 0):

I'm still very green on this, but I'm quickly learning that the web developer is your friend. I was able to identify the parent class needed for this.

```
.ms-rtestate-field ul {}
```